# Non-static error when trying to load filestream to RichTextBox from Gzip decompress procedure

Tags: c#, .net, gzipstream

Basically all I want is to load a Gziped file into a rich text box.  I found some code on the MS .NET site for decompressing the file.  Now I want to point that stream to a rich text box, but I keep getting the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.richTextBox1'   "

Code is here.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

```
public static void Decompress(FileInfo fi)
{
    // Get the stream of the source file.
    using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
    {
        // Get original file extension, for example
        // "doc" from report.doc.gz.
        string curFile = fi.FullName;
        string origName = curFile.Remove(curFile.Length -
                fi.Extension.Length);

        //Create the decompressed file.
        using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(origName))
        {
            using (GZipStream Decompress = new GZipStream(inFile,
                    CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                // Copy the decompression stream 
                // into the output file.
                Decompress.CopyTo(outFile);
                richTextBox1.LoadFile(Decompress.CopyTo(outFile), RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                // problem right here ^^^^


            }//using
        }//using
    }//using
}//DeCompress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a hunch, but try this instead:

```
richTextBox1.LoadFile(outFile, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

The `Decompress.CopyTo(outFile)` is a method and doesn't return anything, which is probably why the LoadFile method is coughing on that line.

Also, change your function to this (you can't have your control referenced in a static method):

```
public void Decompress(FileInfo fi)
```

Comment: You are correct. But that would produce a different compiler error than the one the OP mentioned. It doesn't make sense. Maybe he just pasted in the wrong one.

Comment: @Charles You're right.  The example he lifted is a static method.  "problem right here ^^^^" is pointing to the wrong issue.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is a hack, but basically I dump the uncompressed data to a file then load that file in the RTF.  I'm sure it's much slower than streaming it directly to RTF but I could not get that piece working.  It's functional, but not great.  I pass in the fi variable to Decompress based on what the program arguement is, and I then assign that program to be run when a user double clicks on a gz file in windows.  So the code looks like this:

```
   public void Decompress(FileInfo fi)
    {
        // Get the stream of the source file.
        using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
        {
            // Get original file extension, for example
            // "doc" from report.doc.gz.
            string curFile = fi.FullName;
            string origName = curFile.Remove(curFile.Length -
                    fi.Extension.Length);

            //Create the decompressed file.
            using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(origName))
            {
                using (GZipStream Decompress = new GZipStream(inFile,
                        CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    // Copy the decompression stream 
                    // into the output file.
                    Decompress.CopyTo(outFile);
                    Decompress.Close();
                    outFile.Close();
                    inFile.Close();
                    rtbOut.LoadFile(origName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                    string tmp = rtbOut.Text;
                }//using
            }//using
        }//using
    } //Decompress
```